# Javascript app to receive event on server to run another function visible by clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to make a web application that can receive an event from a client that changes the running function on the server.

I think socket.io on a simple node app is the best way to start for now. In the future, I would like to permit multiple clients to call the function running on the server, while the other clients also view the changes being performed by other clients.

The web app runs using a simple html page with a js file. It runs a function that loops. This function is a simple call to load a gif file on loop. This is already done and works fine on the browser console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("myImg").src= a;
        sleep(5000).then(() => {
        // Do something after the sleep!
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = "img.gif";
        });     
    }
</script>
```

The HTML page simply can respond to events like this:

```
<img id="myImg" src="image.gif" onclick='changeImage("image2.gif")'>
```

I can call changeImage from the browser console. How can I expose this function to be remotely called by a client?

Comment: You wanna expose `changeImage` to be called remotely?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do.